# Laying a blanket over steps

Tags: modeling

I have created some steps in Sketchup and wish to lay a blanket over the steps.
After 2 days trying to use Blender to lay the blanket, I have got stuck - because the plane > physics> cotton, always tears when lowered down onto the steps.
Strangely, using the same settings, I was able to wrap a blanket over a piano without it tearing.. and that had sharp corners too.

Would anyone have a suggestion please?

Thank you
Stephen

Comment: I should have said that I got my settings from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBlPXewajS4

Comment: Can you post an image showing the problem or the blend itself?